# PCMCIA card under linux

Tags: linux, drivers, lan, linux-device-driver, pcmcia

Is it possible to use STLAB 10/100 PCMCIA LAN card under linux? From linux live CD?

Comment: The easiest way is just to use a live USB-stick or live CD and try it out. The speed (10/100) suggests that is rather old. In general, older network cards are good supported under Linux. This website also suggests that there are drivers for Linux available: http://www.e-store.net.au/e/product.php/56/38/10/100%20Base%201-Port%20Lan%20PCMCIA%20/Cardbus%20Adapter

Comment: @Slizzered how can I test it? What should I do to install it? Can I test it with Backtrack VM?

Comment: No, I don't think a VM is sufficient as it will use the Windows driver to talk to the hardware. You can boot the computer from a live CD and see if it is possible to connect to a network. You can also use tools like [lshw -short](https://chrisjean.com/how-to-find-hardware-devices-in-ubuntu-with-lshw/) to see if the card is visible from the live CD

Comment: @Slizzered you can pass througs USB devices to VM, not sure it works with PCMCIA ones.